# Laravel Validation - Validating Associative Array Values Against Each Other Via Custom Rules

Tags: arrays, laravel, validation, laravel-6

Looking through the Laravel documentation concerning array validation I'm having trouble finding a good or standard way of validating the bodies of associative arrays against each other.

In the following example - I want to validate that each incoming comment array has a valid `publish_at` date by making sure that that date comes AFTER its parent Post record's `publish_at` date. Please note that I'm specifically looking for an easy way to pass in a comments contextual array payload to the custom rule and *not* an explicit way to validate this example (i.e. a generalized solution to the problem of validating array values against each other rather than a specific way to validate the presented example).

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'data.attributes.comments' => 'present|array',
            'data.attributes.comments.*.parent_post_id' => 'required|integer|min:1',
            'data.attributes.comments.*.publish_at' => [
                'required',
                'string',
                'date',
                new CommentsPublishAtRule(
                   $this->inputAttribute('comments.*.parent_post_id')
               ),
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Custom Rule Class:

```
class CommentsPublishAtRule implements Rule
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $parent_post_ids_array;

    public function __construct(array $parent_post_ids_array)
    {
        $this->parent_post_ids_array; = $parent_post_ids_array;
    }

    /**
     * This works by first grabbing the index of the current `comments` array
     * (ex: `data/attributes/comments/0/publish_at` => `0`) and then grabbing the corresponding
     * `parent_post_id` from the array of all `data/attributes/comments/n/parent_post_id`s.
     *
     * @param string $attribute
     * @param mixed $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        // Get our index in the attribute array
        $comment_index = (int) filter_var($attribute, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        // Grab out `parent_post_id`
        $parent_post_id = $this->parent_post_ids_array[$comment_index];

        // Check to see if the Post record exists and that the incoming `publish_at` date is valid
        return Posts::query()
            ->WherePostIdIs($parent_post_id)
            ->where('publish_at', '<=', Carbon::parse($value))
            ->exists();
    }
}
```

It would be great if I didn't have to do this odd bit of code here:

```
// Get our index in the attribute array
$comment_index = (int) filter_var($attribute, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
// Grab out `parent_post_id`
$parent_post_id = $this->parent_post_ids_array[$comment_index];
```